# Give anchor element without class specific style

Tags: css, anchor

I am really struggling to find a way to style each category link in a different colour.

So I create a post with 3 category tags e.g. ‘food’, ‘drink’ and ‘fun’

On the news page showing all my different posts which contain the clickable link to each categories I have created. Say I want the food tag to be green and the drink tag to be blue. I cannot seem to be able to find how to do this?

When I inspect the element it shows: `<a href="http://localhost/domain/?cat=19" rel="category">food</a>` for food and `<a href="http://localhost/domain/?cat=20" rel="category">drink</a>` for drink.

There is no class so I can target each one separately in my style sheet. Any ideas how I can style these individually?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome new contributor! Please share with us the complete **HTML** code with these 2 `anchors`. There is a quick solution for this, but to help you better we need a more complete HTML.

Comment: It should be possible to give every category a class name but without more details (eg. theme name, source code of your site, etc) we can't help out.

Comment: Ideally you would add a class to each link and target that class in your CSS. However if that cannot be done then you may use CSS selectors to target the `href` attribute of each link. For example `a[href="http://localhost/domain/?cat=19"] { color: green; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different solutions to give elements without a class an individual styling. One of them is to count the child elements through their parent. How does this look like?

**CSS**

```
.post-categories > li:first-child > a {
    color: red;
}

.post-categories > li:nth-child(2) > a {
    color: blue;
}
```

So for the first child use the pseudo-selector `:first-child` an for each following `:nth-child(#)`, where you add the number for #.

Another solution is this way:

```
a[href="http://localhost/domain/?cat=19"] {
    color: red;
}

a[href="http://localhost/domain/?cat=20"] {
    color: blue;
}
```

However, this asks more from the DOM to search through your page checking each anchor for the matching `href`. The first approach is user friendlier.

Comment: Thank you for your responses the theme I am using is Giga-store.

I am working on local host and have no means to put it live yet. In the content.php code it is: 
<div class="delccc"> 
<?php the_category( ); ?> 
</div>

when inspected the HTML is: 
<div class="delccc">
<ul class-"post-categories">
<li>
<a href="http://localhost/domain/?cat=19" rel="category">food</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

The other links are the same but 19 is changed to 20, 21 etc..

Comment: @DelDel I have updated the answer. From your comment I assume that each category comes like this <li><a href="..">food</a></li><li><a href="..">drink</a></li>. If so, than the answer should be good now. Let me know.

Comment: OMG That worked!! Many thanks for that and my misses thanks you! She said will this now stop me being grumpy! :) 

I used: a[href="http://localhost/domain/?cat=20"] {
    color: blue;
}


I had know idea I could use this method in CSS, many thanks again :)

Comment: Glad it worked, please mark my answer as the solution, and success with further development.